# Jboss 7 App servers : Dividing work by type of task

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, cluster-computing

Love to know ways to divide up work between clusters. Meaning send Request page A.b, API function 1 and 2 to cluster 1 (jboss app servers); Function 3 & 4 to cluster 2, etc

Main domain would be the same, sub url can be different. One way would be to have ejbs and set beans to be alive on a certain clutser/ set of servers only, what are the other ways?

Especially interested in ways that can be changed at run time. So if a few nodes go down or load patterns change, we can re define the clusters..

---

More detailed:
We have 3,000 strings per language and more than 120 broad operations that a user can do. The institutional users can (expected to be 50%) do bulk operations. Plus we have 12 languages to support. Expose a web UI and web service API.

Suggested we use clusters of servers for specific languages. This is so less data has to be cached per server and we the code can optimize it self when the JVM is warmed up for particular operations.

English is the default language. We are okay with the initial txn (login for API/ first page for UI) come to a set of servers that have all the English and the initial text for other languages (the screen where translations will be entered will have a attribute to denote if it should be loaded as part of the default set.

Issue we are facing is how to route requests? We can have JMS queues but how do you route the initial request ?

We plan to have about 70 Jboss server instances in the app later for initial release. One node will be able to do a all work if needed to (like if another crashes) but in the best case we would like to only send it work of a couple of languages and task types.

We will have a web and app layer, separated by a firewall. Question is :
code snippets/ techniques samples to route different languages and request types to different app server clusters.

Some simple one are : 
1. for the lanuage see some cookie or header or form param
2. for work type - besides a big if statement - is there any data driven better way?

But how to make the request go to a particular cluster? EJB that are deployed in certain clusters only? JMS queses that are consumed in certain clusters only?

Using Java 7, Jboss 7 on linux. Open to Jboss specific or linux specific or (best) J2EE solutions.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the language will make any difference? Have you profiled it? This will complicate your deployments so you need to be quite sure it's worth it.

Comment: Yes we run out of memory. Right now its been given 2GB (each instance). And it runs faster when only 2-3 lang requests go to a particular node. Else fails out performance benchmarks

Comment: What will be cool is to have run time reloadable rules to change routing so we can add nodes or change number of nodes in cluster. We are keeping language strings in RAM so its faster.

Comment: @artbristol we can do without languag but then have to rely on external caches. not a problem except slower. want to try and keep everything possible in same jvm.

Comment: can't you just have different user-facing urls per task? it should be straightforward then to split traffic by task type urls. you would have a front end load balancer or server to split the processing then, before the request is actually sent to JBoss servers.

Comment: Yes that would work. but wanted a way to distribute both internal API requests and those originating from the web UI. Internal calls to API from other apps in the company will come thru internal LAN/ VPN

Answer (score 2):

Many web frameworks allow the adoption of a strategy where the strings are not loaded in memory in the server, but instead are sent as a compressed bundle to the client.

The server only sends labels with the label key such as `user.address.street.name`, and it's up to the client to match the key to the correct language-specifc string.

The client only needs to download the bundle it needs. There can be several bundles per language, to group strings that are normally used together and reduce the download bundle size, but this is probably not needed.

The client language bundle is served to the client with the caching headers populated, so that when the customer logs out or closes the browser and returns later the bundle is still cached and does not need to be re-downloaded.

One frameworks that adopts this strategy is for example GWT with it's [client-side language bundles](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#I18N).

Comment: thanks this really helps, but we are too way in for this now. have been able to differnt different ejbs in different clusters, this is one way. and gets us some txn mgt where we need. still looking for better ways esp where we can change at run time

Comment: You did not answer my query but gave useful info and see no point in wasting the 50 rep ! Hence question is not answered for now. thank you though!